# Changing "voted close" option after finding better reference

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I've voted close to this question [Save and retrieve ArrayList<String> in an ordered manner from sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785714/save-and-retrieve-arrayliststring-in-an-ordered-manner-from-sharedpreferences) with "Duplicate of..." set to [Misbehavior when trying to store a string set using SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034803/misbehavior-when-trying-to-store-a-string-set-using-sharedpreferences). However, after further reading the SO, I've found out that the right "duplicated of..." should be [android SharedPreferences putStringSet order/sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446367/android-sharedpreferences-putstringset-order-sort). So, I retracted my vote to change the reference. I found out that I can't re-vote after retracting it. Can you help me set the reference to the later one?

Comment: OOT: is meta has been doing clean up recently? I found out that I'm marked as "New contributor" and this is the first meta question :D

Comment: If you had asked a question at any point, it was deleted later on. Hence, "new contributor". Makes sense? No. It does not make sense.

Comment: Don't worry, we'll be nice to you.

Comment: @usr2564301 please, speak for yourself ;)

Comment: @yivi I don't delete my question. So, I guess there's been some question clean ups recently. Nevermind, just a little shocked with the "New contributor" title

Comment: Posts are deleted regularly because. Either via votes or by roomba. Both here and in main. No “recent cleanup”.

Comment: @yivi I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: it does and this meta question also does help marked the right SO question as the "duplicate"